# Ruby: how to convert an array of strings into a hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to convert an array like this:

```
codes = ["AAAA 2.0", "BBBB 1.0", "CCCC n/a", "DDDD"]
```

into a hash like this:

```
codes = {
  "AAAA" => "2.0",
  "BBBB" => "1.0",
  "CCCC" => "n/a",
  "DDDD" => ""
}
```

Any thoughts how to handle this the best way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
hash = {}
codes.each { |a| hash[a.split[0]] = a.split[1].to_s }
hash
#=> {"AAAA"=>"2.0", "BBBB"=>"1.0", "CCCC"=>"n/a", "DDDD"=>""}
```

Alternatively (if you are ok with `""` being `nil`):

```
Hash[codes.map(&:split)]
#=> {"AAAA"=>"2.0", "BBBB"=>"1.0", "CCCC"=>"n/a", "DDDD"=>nil}
```

Comment: `.map(&:split)` looks better:)

Comment: yeah. I posted it as alternative solution because here `"DDDD"=>nil`.

Comment: Interesting that `[["DDDD"]].to_h` raises an error but `Hash[["DDDD"]]` works successfully

Comment: @shivam - thank you. I've used: codes_h = Hash[codes.map(&:split)] but got an error: "invalid number of elements (3 for 1..2) (Argument error)".

Comment: @msayen that will happen only when an element in `codes` has 3 words, which was not part of your question example.

Comment: @shivam - thank you once again! Yes, you're right, I had one "wrong" element in `codes`. Now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
codes.map { |s| s.split(/\s+/).tap { |a| a << "" if a.size==1 } }.to_h
  #=> {"AAAA"=>"2.0", "BBBB"=>"1.0", "CCCC"=>"n/a", "DDDD"=>""}
```

The steps are as follows.

```
codes.map { |s| s.split(/\s+/) }
  #=> [["AAAA", "2.0"], ["BBBB", "1.0"], ["CCCC", "n/a"], ["DDDD"]]
```

As we want to convert this to a hash, I would like to append an empty string to each of these arrays that are of size 1. [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) provides a convenient way of doing that:

```
b = codes.map { |s| s.split(/\s+/).tap { |a| a << "" if a.size==1 } }
  #=> [["AAAA", "2.0"], ["BBBB", "1.0"], ["CCCC", "n/a"], ["DDDD", ""]]
```

`tap` takes the result of `s.split(/\s+/)`, represented by the block variable `a`  and appends `""` if it is of size 1. `a` is returned by `tap`, whether it has been altered or not. Lastly,

```
 b.to_h
   #=> {"AAAA"=>"2.0", "BBBB"=>"1.0", "CCCC"=>"n/a", "DDDD"=>""}
```